# Enforcing a unique constraint on a column encrypted with cell level encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, constraints

I want to enforce a unique constraint on a column which must be encrypted in MSSQL 2005 using Cell Level Encyption (CLE).

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'itsaSECRET!!!3£3£3£!!!'
CREATE CERTIFICATE ERCERT WITH SUBJECT = 'A cert for use by procs'

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY ERKEY 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ERCERT

-- This illustrates the point. 
-- The results differ
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    [Email] [varbinary](254) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ERKEY DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ERCERT 
    insert into @TempTable(Email) VALUES(EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('ERKEY'), N'duplicate'))
    insert into @TempTable(Email) VALUES(EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('ERKEY'), N'duplicate'))
    insert into @TempTable(Email) VALUES(EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('ERKEY'), N'duplicate'))
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY ERKEY   

select * from @TempTable
```

The output makes it obvious why the constraint has 'not' been enforced. (Please excuse the awesomeness of my ascii-art.)

```
    Email
   -------
1 | 0x00703529AF46D24BA863A3534260374E01000000328909B51BA44A49510F24DF31C46F2E30977626D96617E2BD13D9115EB578852EEBAE326B8F3E2D422230478A29767C
2 | 0x00703529AF46D24BA863A3534260374E01000000773E06E1B53F2C57F97C54370FECBB45BC8A154FEA5CEEB9B6BB1133305282328AAFAD65B9BDC595F0006474190F6482
3 | 0x00703529AF46D24BA863A3534260374E01000000C9EDB1C83B52E60598038D832D34D75867AB0ABB23F9044B7EBC76832F22C432A867078D10974DC3717D6086D3031BDB
```

But, how do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you could use "deterministic encryption", for example, AES ECB mode, or AES-SIV. But since you are within the limitations of SQL Server encryption, you'll have to find another way. Here is an old post that discusses the issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/03/11/549754.aspx. Here is a newer post that mentions that SQL Server 2016 will support deterministic encryption: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/sql-server-2016-security-roadmap-session-notes-msignite/, which is what you are looking for.